# How to change name of uploaded file in php?

Tags: php, upload, rename

I have this code to upload jpg files. I need to rename the file that someone uploads to newtexture.jpg'.

```
<?php
$demo_mode = false;
$upload_dir = 'uploads/';
$allowed_ext = array('jpg','jpeg');

if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'post'){
    exit_status('Error! Wrong HTTP method!');
}

if(array_key_exists('pic',$_FILES) && $_FILES['pic']['error'] == 0 ){
    $pic = $_FILES['pic'];
    if(!in_array(get_extension($pic['name']),$allowed_ext)){
        exit_status('Only '.implode(',',$allowed_ext).' files are allowed!');
    }   
    if($demo_mode){
        $line = implode('       ', array( date('r'), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $pic['size'], $pic['name']));
        file_put_contents('log.txt', $line.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        exit_status('Uploads are ignored in demo mode.');
    }
    if(move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$pic['name'])){
        exit_status('File was uploaded successfuly!');
    }
}
exit_status('Something went wrong with your upload!');

function exit_status($str){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>$str));
    exit;
}

function get_extension($file_name){
    $ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $ext = array_pop($ext);
    return strtolower($ext);
}
?>
```

PS. It says that it is mostly coded so to add more details? What else... I am a student and I need it for my Capstone project and it is an emergency...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument in [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file) is the new filename, so all you need to do is change it to what you want.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.'newtexture.jpg')){
```

Comment: Thank you! I wish I had more than 15 reputation :)

Comment: @FragkiskosMysirlakis actually, you do now :)

Comment: Yes, haha I do have now...

Answer (score 1):

Pass your file name as a second argument in [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file)

```
$fileName = 'newtexture.jpg';

if(move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$fileName)){
```

Comment: You said to pass file name as a second argument, but you passed path to new file. So what solution is corrent?

Answer (score 1):

[move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) takes **two** arguments:

1. The temporary file name to move.
2. The new permanent file path.

> ```
> bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
> ```

So, You'll have to specify the second parameter (path + the new file name).
E.g.

```
move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.'newtexture.jpg')
```