# How to append a time/datestamp to a file name in an html file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an html form with an image upload section and it works fine, however for data management reasons I would like the image file name to have the time/datestamp added to it when it uploads.

What used to happen, was that if the file would be uploaded via a phone it would be called image.jpg which would be overwritten if a new file by the same name would be uploaded (understandably)

However what I want to have happen, is that the file would be called something like image091118151821 for the 11 September 2018 15:18:21. or something like that.

The HTML Form:

```
<form method="POST" action="incident-submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
div class="element-date"><label class="title">Date</label><input class="large" data-format="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date" name="date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/></div>
    <div class="element-input"><label class="title">Division</label><input class="large" type="text" name="input" /></div>
    <div class="element-input"><label class="title">Location within Division</label><input class="large" type="text" name="input1" /></div>
    <div class="element-input"><label class="title">Employee Division</label><input class="large" type="text" name="input2" /></div>
    <div class="element-textarea"><label class="title">Cause of events</label><textarea class="large" name="textarea" cols="20" rows="5" ></textarea></div>


<input type="file" name="image">
</div>
<div>
  <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
</div>
```

And the PHP that submits the data to the database:

```
// If upload button is clicked ...
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    // Get image name
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    // Get text

    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $division = $_POST['input'];
    $location = $_POST['input1'];
    $employeedivision = $_POST['input2'];
    $events = $_POST['textarea'];

    // image file directory
    $target = "img/".basename($image);

...
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
}else{
    $msg = "Failed to upload image";
}
```

I then changed the

```
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
```

line to:

```
$image = $_FILES['image'.date('m-d-Y_hia').'.jpg']['name'.date('m-d-Y_hia').'.jpg'];
```

And it seems to not upload anything

Is there a way I can cause that to happen, it does not have to be done in php, javascript is also fine

Could someone help me solve this conundrum?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change name of uploaded file in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444798/how-to-change-name-of-uploaded-file-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Using the handy `pathinfo()` function you can dig out all the seperate parts of a filename. Then just use those and the `date()` function to build the filename of your choice.

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);

$dest_filename = $path_parts['filename'] . date('mdyHis') . '.' . $path_parts['extension'];

// image file directory
$target = "img/$dest_filename";
```

If you want to seperate the filename from the date to make it a little easier to read you could try

```
$dest_filename = $path_parts['filename'] . 
                 '_' . 
                 date('mdyHis') . 
                 '.' . 
                 $path_parts['extension'];
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change this line

```
$target = "img/".basename($image);
```

to:

```
$target = "img/".basename(explode('.',$image)[0] . date('m-d-Y_hia') . explode('.',$image)[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it nearly works, the only thing is, that the "." is missing before the file extention. .i.e. IMG_794409-11-2018_0858amJPG instead of IMG_794409-11-2018_0858am.JPG

Comment: Be careful using this method, you may lose the extension and a part of the file name. Imagine a file called "image.white.jpg" would result in something like: "image.1474741.white"
Also exploding two time the exact same string two times in a row isn't a good practice